# How to SELECT geometry data from a geoJson in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, geometry, gis, geojson

I want to get all the data from a geoJSON to insert it then in a table with a GEOMETRY type.

The file can be downloaded on [opendata.arcgis.com](https://public-nps.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/nps::nps-boundary-1/about).

Everything is ok except the geometry data returned is NULL from the following query.

```
SELECT
    x.UNIT_NAME,
    x.UNIT_CODE,
    x.geometry
FROM
    NPS
CROSS JOIN json_table(
    doc,
    '$.features[*]' columns (
        UNIT_NAME varchar(50) PATH '$.properties.UNIT_NAME',
        UNIT_CODE varchar(50) PATH '$.properties.UNIT_CODE',
        geometry geometry PATH '$.geometry' 
    )
) x
```

MySQL Result

```
UNIT_NAME|UNIT_CODE|geometry
Appalachian National Scenic Trail|APPA|NULL
White House|WHHO|NULL
```

An abstract of the file is here:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "NPS_-_Land_Resources_Division_Boundary_and_Tract_Data_Service",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "OBJECTID": 1,
                "UNIT_CODE": "APPA",
                "GIS_Notes": "Lands - http://landsnet.nps.gov/tractsnet/documents/APPA/Metadata/appa_metadata.xml",
                "UNIT_NAME": "Appalachian National Scenic Trail",
                "DATE_EDIT": "2021-12-07T00:00:00Z",
                "STATE": "ME",
                "REGION": "NE",
                "GNIS_ID": "2766084",
                "UNIT_TYPE": "National Scenic Trail",
                "CREATED_BY": "Lands",
                "METADATA": "https://irma.nps.gov/DataStore/Reference/Profile/2259619",
                "PARKNAME": "Appalachian",
                "CreationDate": "2022-01-06T10:43:45Z",
                "Creator": "WASO",
                "EditDate": "2022-01-06T10:43:45Z",
                "Editor": "WASO",
                "GlobalID": "3923bec4-1652-41ca-a444-84fead65aba5",
                "Shape__Area": 1483097401.5976601,
                "Shape__Length": 5738045.6635156097
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [-84.2329423255553, 34.623125245778901],
                            [-69.029418383436607, 45.847784381666997],
                            [-69.029490112115397, 45.849869184805797],
                            [-69.029642890392395, 45.854309758604899]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "OBJECTID": 2,
                "UNIT_CODE": "WHHO",
                "GIS_Notes": "Lands - http://landsnet.nps.gov/tractsnet/documents/WHHO/Metadata/whho_metadata.xml",
                "UNIT_NAME": "White House",
                "DATE_EDIT": "2010-05-28T00:00:00Z",
                "STATE": "DC",
                "REGION": "NC",
                "GNIS_ID": "2733430",
                "UNIT_TYPE": "Other Designation",
                "CREATED_BY": "Lands",
                "METADATA": "https://irma.nps.gov/DataStore/Reference/Profile/2165312",
                "PARKNAME": "President's Park (White House)",
                "CreationDate": "2022-01-06T10:44:35Z",
                "Creator": "WASO",
                "EditDate": "2022-01-06T10:44:35Z",
                "Editor": "WASO",
                "GlobalID": "c1455489-c4ea-40e8-b063-187c68391fac",
                "Shape__Area": 122787.890625,
                "Shape__Length": 1366.0892805429
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [-77.037852226846397, 38.8963431043125],
                        [-77.037852298711599, 38.8964779997699],
                        [-77.037853394656295, 38.8985426714681],
                        [-77.035259846141599, 38.898543483148799],
                        [-77.035258759180095, 38.896343916717498]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your geometry is a json and must be handled as such

Comment: not really but you can try https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172428/converting-spatial-data-from-oracle-to-mysql

Answer (score 0):

**There was 2 problems:**

1. in the `SELECT`, if forgot to add `ST_GeomFromGeoJson()`
2. in the `CROSS JOIN json_table()`. I had the wrong data type for the `"geometry: {}"` json object. Instead of `geometry geometry PATH '$.geometry'`, the correct data type is `geometry json PATH '$.geometry'`.

Full correct query below:

```
SELECT
    X.UNIT_NAME,
    X.UNIT_CODE,
    ST_GEOMFROMGEOJSON(X.GEOMETRY)
FROM
    NPS
CROSS JOIN json_table(
        doc,
        '$.features[*]' COLUMNS(
            UNIT_NAME VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.properties.UNIT_NAME',
            UNIT_CODE VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.properties.UNIT_CODE',
            GEOMETRY JSON PATH '$.geometry'
        )
    ) X
```